# If $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is Fibonacci Number, prove that the sequence$\left\{\frac{\ln a_n}{\ln a_{n+1}}\right\}$ increase

Tags: inequality, fibonacci-numbers

> If $a_0=1,a_1=1,a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$, prove the sequence$\left\{\frac{\ln a_n}{\ln a_{n+1}}\right\},\,n\geq 1$ increase.

When $n$ is even this inequality is easy proved by Am-Gm.

If $n$ is even,we have $$\frac{\ln a_n}{\ln a_{n+1}}<\frac{\ln a_{n+1}}{\ln a_{n+2}}\Leftrightarrow \ln a_n\cdot\ln a_{n+2}<(\ln a_{n+1})^2$$

By Am-Gm, and $a_{n-1}a_{n+1}-a_n^2=(-1)^n$, we have$$LHS<\left(\frac{\ln a_n+\ln a_{n+2}}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\ln(a_n\cdot a_{n+2})}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\ln(a_{n+1}^2-1)}{2}\right)^2<RHS.$$

But when n is odd, the inequality is a little difficult, or I didn't use a right method.

**Supplement:**

Here we prove that $$a_{n-1}a_{n+1}-a_n^2=(-1)^n.$$

It is not hard to prove that if $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$then$$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-1}&a_n\\
a_n&a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}$$by induction. So $$a_{n-1}a_{n+_1}-a_n^2=\det\begin{vmatrix}
0&1\\
1&1
\end{vmatrix}^n=\left(\det\begin{vmatrix}
0&1\\
1&1
\end{vmatrix}\right)^n=(-1)^n$$

Comment: Can you explain your  **even** case a little more? Also I think you have a typo, $(\ln a_{n+2})^2$ should be $(\ln a_{n+1})^2$

Comment: $\frac{\ln a_n}{\ln a_{n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}+O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})$ hence increasing from some point onwards.

Comment: @Chrystomath:Is there any article about it?

Comment: @Vstal Idk but you can use $a_n=(\phi^n+(-1)^{n+1}\phi^{-n})/\sqrt5$.

Comment: Actually when you define Fibonacci with $a_0=a_1=1$ then the Cassini identity should look like $a_{n-1}a_{n+1}-a_n^2=(-1)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

There is a primary proof by a student in Fudan University(**Not me**).

First, it is easy to prove that $\left\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right\}$ strictly increase.

Second, we can also prove $$0\leq\ln(1+x)\leq x,\quad(\forall\,x\geq 0).$$

And now we begin the proof.

Consider $\forall\,n\geq 3$, we have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\cdot\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}=\frac{9}{4}.$$

So
$$
\ln a_{n+1}-\ln a_{n-1}\geq\ln\frac{9}{4}=2\ln\frac{3}{2}>\frac{4}{5}\Rightarrow(\ln a_{n+1}-\ln a_{n-1})^2>\frac{16}{25}
$$

By this inequality when $n\geq 5$ we can get
$$
\begin{align*}
\ln a_{n+1}\cdot\ln a_{n-1}&=\frac{1}{4}(\ln a_{n+1}+\ln a_{n-1})^2-\frac{1}{4}
(\ln a_{n+1}-\ln a_{n-1})^2\\
&< \frac{1}{4}(\ln a_{n+1}+\ln a_{n-1})^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a_{n+1}\cdot a_{n-1}))^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a_{n}^2+(-1)^{n-1}))^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a_{n}^2+(-1)^{n-1}))^2-\frac{1}{4}(\ln a_n^2)^2+(\ln a_n)^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a_n^2+1))^2-\frac{1}{4}(\ln a_n^2)^2+(\ln a_n)^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a_n^2+1)-\ln a_n^2)(\ln(a_n^2+1)+\ln a_n^2)+(\ln a_n)^2-\frac{4}{25}
\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln(a_n^2+1)-\ln a_n^2\right)\cdot2\ln((a_n+1)^2)+(\ln a_n)^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&=\ln(1+\frac{1}{a_n^2})\ln(1+a_n)+(\ln a_n)^2-\frac{4}{25}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{a_n^2}\cdot a_n-\frac{4}{25}+(\ln a_n)^2\\
&\leq\frac{1}{8}-\frac{4}{25}+(\ln a_n)^2\\
&<(\ln a_n)^2
\end{align*}
$$

In a word, it is $\ln a_{n-1}\cdot\ln a_{n+1}<(\ln a_n)^2$, which is equal to$$\frac{\ln a_{n-1}}{\ln a_n}<\frac{\ln a_n}{\ln a_{n+1}},\quad n\geq 5.$$

For the rest situation ,we just need to prove it by caculating it.

Comment: Can you explain more? For example, shouldn't fourth line  be $a_{n+1}a_{n-1}=a_n^2\pm1$?

Comment: @Chrystomath:Sorry, I will add it on the question.Please see the question's supplement.

Comment: $\ln a_{n+1}\cdot\ln a_n = \ldots$ should probably be $\ln a_{n+1}\cdot\ln a_{n-1} = \ldots$.

Comment: I've found couple more typos, but overall it seems correct. I took the liberty and fixed all these typos, feel free to check/correct ... (also added few $<$ so that it is clear you got $<$ in the end, not $\leq$)

Comment: The first line is false right? $ a_{n+1} / a_n $ is not strictly increasing. It oscillates around the golden ratio.

Comment: -1 Also, $ 1/8 - 4/25 < 0$, so we don't have the penultimate inequality. @Sil Can you review again?

Comment: @CalvinLin That line about strictly increasing $a_{n+1} / a_n$ is false indeed, but I haven't seen it used anywhere. The $1/8 - 4/25 < 0$ seems fine (it gives $(\ln a_n)^2-\frac{7}{200}<(\ln a_n)^2$)

Comment: 1) It is used in justifying that $a_{n+1} / a_{n-1} \geq ... \geq 9/4$ . That is a true statement in itself, but needs to be demonstrated in another way. 2) Ah yes, that inequality is fine. Retracting my downvote.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ad 1) Right, that's why I ignored it, i proved it entirely differently :) (it follows quite elementary from definitions...). Agree that OP should mention that part.