# A Fibonacci conjecture: $\log_{F_{n+1}}{F_n}<\log_{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, fibonacci-numbers

Given the Fibonacci sequence $F_n$, that is $$F_1=F_2=1,F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n.$$
I find that
$$
\log_21<\log_32<\log_53<\log_85<\cdots,
$$
i.e. we have $$
\log_{F_{n+1}}{F_n}<\log_{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}, \quad \text{for} \; n\geqslant1\tag{1}
$$
If $n=2k$, $(1)$ is easy to get, but if $n=2k+1$, I have no idea to prove it.

What's more, if we let $F_1=a,F_2=b$ be two positive integers, then $(1)$ still exstis when $n$ is greater than some integer $m$.

I do not konw whether my conjecture is true.

Comment: @Sil I just use the Cassini's identity, so only get a half of proof.

Comment: Can you add your “easy proof” for even $n$ to the question?

Comment: @Martin R Just use Cassini's identity and the Base inequality,  you can get  $\frac{\ln F_n}{\ln F_{n+1}}-\frac{\ln F_{n+1}}{\ln F_{n+2}}<0$.

Comment: The same question has been asked and self-answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4009705/42969. I haven't checked if the solution is complete.

Comment: @Sil Good point, I seemed to have had a bad confusion myself there! Deleted the comment, it was actually pretty bad. The same mistake was made in the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conjecture**: $ \log_{F_{n+1} } F_n < \log_{F_{n+2} }F_{n+1}.$

This is equivalent to:
$$\dfrac{\log F_{n}}{\log F_{n+1}} < \dfrac{\log    F_{n+1}}{\log F_{n+2}}$$
Multiply both sides by $\log F_{n+1}\log F_{n+2}$ and you'll get  $\log(F_n )\log (F_{n+2}) < (\log (F_{n+1}))^2$ ($\log$ here is the natural logarithm).

One can use the Cassini identity ($F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} \pm 1$) to prove your conjecture, but first let's establish an inequality equivalent to the above one,
$$\log(F_n)\log(F_{n+2})< (\log(F_{n+1}))^2 = (\frac{1}2\log(F_{n+1}^2))^2 = \frac{1}{4}(\log(F_{n+1})^2)^2$$

Therefore it suffices to prove that $\log(F_{n+1}^2)^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$

Case 1: when $F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} - 1$
$$(\log(F_{n+2}/F_{n}))^2 > (\log 2)^2 > \dfrac{2 \log F_n}{F_n} + \dfrac{2\log 3F_n}{F_n} - \dfrac{1}{F_n^2}$$
$$\geq \dfrac{2 \log F_n + 2\log (2F_n + F_{n-1})}{F_n}- \dfrac{1}{F_n^2} = \dfrac{2 \log F_n + 2\log (F_{n+2})}{F_n}- \dfrac{1}{F_n^2}$$
$$\implies (\log F_{n+2} - \log F_n)^2 > \dfrac{2 \log F_nF_{n+2}}{F_n} - \dfrac{1}{F_n^2}$$
for a sufficiently large $n$($n \geq 8$ for the Fibonacci sequence starting with $1$ and $2$). Now add $4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$ to both sides:
$$(\log F_{n+2} + \log F_n)^2 > \dfrac{2 \log F_nF_{n+2}}{F_n} - \dfrac{1}{F_n^2} + 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2} $$
$$\implies (\log F_{n+2} + \log F_n)^2 - \dfrac{2 \log F_nF_{n+2}}{F_n} + \dfrac{1}{F_n^2} > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$$
$$\implies (\log F_{n} + \log F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$$
$$\implies (\log F_{n} + \log (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n}))^2 = (\log(F_n\cdot (F_{n+2} - \dfrac{1}{F_n})))^2 = \log(F_{n+1}^2)^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2} $$

Case 2: when $F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} + 1$
$$(\log F_{n+2} - \log F_n)^2 > 0 $$
$$\implies (\log F_{n+2} +\log F_n)^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$$
$$\implies (\log F_{n+1}^2)^2 = (\log F_{n+2}F_n + 1)^2 > (\log F_{n+2}F_n)^2 > 4\log F_n \log F_{n+2}$$

Verifying the inequality for $n < 8$ manually completes the proof using Cassini's identity.

Answer (score 0):

For even $n$ you can use:

$$F_nF_{n+2}<F_{n+1}^2$$

$$\implies \log(F_nF_{n+2})<\log(F_{n+1}^2)$$

$$\implies \log(F_n)+\log(F_{n+2})<2\log(F_{n+1})$$

$$\implies \frac{\log(F_n)+\log(F_{n+2})}{2}<\log(F_{n+1})$$

By the AM-GM:

$$\sqrt{\log(F_n)\log(F_{n+2})}<\frac{\log(F_n)+\log(F_{n+2})}{2}< \log(F_{n+1})$$

as required.

Comment: $F_nF_{n+2}< F_{n+1}^2$ holds only for even $n$.

Comment: @MartinR; good point!

Comment: Yep. If $n$ is even, it is easy  to get. But it seems to be hard when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

In general, starting with any two numbers, you get
$$F_n=A\phi^n+B(-\phi)^{-n}$$
where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ is the golden ratio. The second term soon becomes very small.  So
$$\ln F_n\ln F_n-\ln F_{n-1}\ln F_{n+1}\approx \\
[n\ln\phi+\ln A]^2-[(n-1)\ln\phi+\ln A][(n+1)\ln\phi+\ln A]\\
\approx (\ln\phi)^2$$

Answer (score -1):

**Conjecture**:$ \log_{F_{n+1} } F_n < \log_{F_{n+2} }F_{n+1}.$

This is equivalent to:
$$\dfrac{\log F_{n}}{\log F_{n+1}} < \dfrac{\log    F_{n+1}}{\log F_{n+2}}$$
Multiply both sides by $\log F_{n+1}\log F_{n+2}$ and you'll get  $\log(F_n )\log (F_{n+2}) < (\log (F_{n+1}))^2$ ($\log$ here is the natural logarithm).

One can use the Cassini identity ($F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} \pm 1$) to prove your conjecture, but first,
$$\log(F_n)\log(F_{n+2})< (\log(F_{n+1}))^2 = (\frac{1}2\log(F_{n+1}^2))^2 = \frac{1}{4}(\log(F_{n+1})^2)^2$$

Case 1: when $F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} - 1$
$$4\log(F_n)\log(F_{n+2})< (\log(F_{n+1})^2)^2 = \log(F_nF_{n+2} - 1)^2 < (\log F_n + \log F_{n+2})^2.$$

Case 2: when $F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} + 1$

$$ 4\log(F_n) \log(F_{n+2})< (\log(F_{n+1})^2)^2 = (\log(F_n F_{n+2} + 1))^2 < (\log(F_n F_{n+2}) + 1)^2 = (\log F_n + \log F_{n+2})^2 + 2\log(F_n F_{n+2}) + 1.$$

Comment: I have a confusion now, we need to prove that $\log (F_n)\log (F_{n+2})<(\log (F_{n+1})^2$, and you just use it?

Comment: @Mr.He Okay, I will add the proof to that.

Comment: I mean that you want to prove $ \log (F_n)\log (F_{n+2})<(\log(F^2_{n+1}))^2$, but in your statement, you have used it. So I think there is some Logical problem in the proof.

Comment: @Mr.He you are right. I have uploaded another proof using Cassini's identitiy.